# sem_wait doesn't return when semaphore is being posted

Tags: c++, c, synchronization, pthreads, semaphore

In two different process, there is a semaphore initialized in a shared memory. In one of the processes, it is being continuously posted. Here is a part of the second process code:

```
sem_init(&(memoryUpper.data()->write), 1, 1);

while(threadIsRunning)
{
    std::cerr << __FILE__ << " :: " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    sem_wait(&(memoryUpper.data()->write));
    std::cerr << __FILE__ << " :: " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
}
```

However, the second process doesn't pass `sem_wait` more than once.

Testing the same code in a more clean process without thread makes it work. Also turning `sem_wait(...)` to `while(sem_trywait(...))` fixes the problem. On the other hand a SIGINT prints the outputs that was intended to be printed before interrupting.

P.S.: It shouldn't be a problem of cout buffer as I have already tested it with a handmade segmentation fault after waiting for the 10th time and it works just as before.

Comment: What does the other thread (whre the semaphore is posted) look like? Are you sure, that it is actually running?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, it has prints before and after semaphore post.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example): http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I might be mistaken, but i don't think the error lies in the code you show.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't repeat the problem in another example. I'll try again!